# How to draw lines with lines() without preceding call to plot() in R

Tags: r, plot

Given these data:

```
> x <- c(1, 2)
> y1 <- c(4, 3)
> y2 <- c(3, 6)
```

I'd like to draw lines for (x, y1) and (x, y2) in different colors on the same plotting frame. This has the desired effect:

```
> plot (x, y1, type='l', col='red')
> lines (x, y2, col='green')
```

Is there a way to do that using `lines` for both lines? This creates just an empty plot:

```
> plot.new ()
> lines (x, y1, col='red')
> lines (x, y2, col='green')
```

I guess `plot` is calling some function to get the plot started before drawing the first line; it doesn't appear to be `plot.new`. What is that function? Can I call it myself before calling `lines`?

EDIT: I am working with R 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `?x11` suggests that it can do that job.

Comment: @Frank I tried `x11()`, `x11(type="Xlib")`, and `x11(type="cairo")`, following each one with `plot.new()` since otherwise `lines` complains that `plot.new` was not called, but still getting the same result (namely an empty plotting window).

Comment: If you do not call plot, then you do not have a coordinate system. If you want to play around with isolated segments, boxes and circles then you should be using the grid-package. It's default coordinate system is c(0,0) to c(1,1). You would need to do some scaling which is what plot does for you when yo call it with either data or xlim and ylim. Look at `?plot.window`

Comment: @BondedDust "If you do not call plot, then you do not have a coordinate system" -- thanks, this is the key point.

Comment: Physics was my first major. Physicists get lost without coordinate systems. I had a hard time grasping topology because so much of it was coordinate-free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 x <- c(1, 2)
 y1 <- c(4, 3)
 y2 <- c(3, 6)
 plot.new(); plot.window(xlim=c(1,2),ylim=c(1,6) )
 lines (x, y1, col='red')
 lines (x, y2, col='green')
```

[image]

I'm getting a nattering message about explaining my code but I do think Robert is smart enough to figure this out. Following the links on the `?plot.window` page lets you see other low-level functions like `?xy.coords`. You can see the code for `plot.default` by typing its name at a console prompt. In that code you see a new function defined but it is really just gathering some parameters before calling `plot.window`:

```
localWindow <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) plot.window(...)
# which gets called later in the code.
```

Comment: "I'm getting a nattering message" -- ha ha, I have to love the hectoring and hand-wringing which is so common on SO.

Comment: I see now that the key problem is to find the appropriate limits for the coordinate system, which `plot` handles automatically. Is there a way to tell R to update the coordinate system after the fact? E.g. something like: `plot.window(xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1))`, `lines(...)`, `lines(...)`, ... then update coordinate system to accommodate all the lines and redraw everything?

Comment: One could I suppose. I earlier thought that `xy.coords` would do the scaling for you, but when I looked at the code, the scaling to [0,1] x [0,1] on the basis of `xlim` and `ylim` appears to be a lower level operation done in compiled code by `plot.xy`. There are also methods for breaking the output device into sections withing which one can plot. The grid package takes this to another level of sophistication with viewPorts.

Answer (score 3):

For `plot` solution, you need to create a `plot` with some data and **mask** those data with `n` option (I also employed `ann=F` to mask `x` and `y` labels):

```
plot(x, y1, type='n', ann=F, xlim=c(1,2),ylim=c(1,6))
lines (x, y2, col='green')
lines (x, y1, col='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the `plot()` command, use `type="n"` to set up the plot invisibly. Then add your line segments with successive `lines()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With `plot(type="n")` I get an error: `argument "x" is missing, with no default` I am working with R 3.0.2 if it matters.

Comment: My apologies for being too brief. You would still need to have an x and y in your plot statement  as you did already in your initial code. The only change I was suggesting was using the type="n" instead of type="l". I know your question was to avoid using the plot() command but I thought this might get you what you wanted.